# How to recreate pyramid triangle?

Tags: python, recursion

I have to write a *recursive* function `asterisk_triangle` which takes an integer and then returns an asterisk triangle consisting of that many lines.

As an example this is a 4 line asterisk triangle.

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
```

I have tried this function:

```
def asterix_triangle(depth):
            rows = [ (depth-i)*' ' + i*2*'*' + '*'   for i in range(depth-1) ]
            for i in rows:
            print i
```

And the following function:

```
def asterisk_triangle(rows=n):
    pyramid_width = n * 2
    for asterisks in range(1, pyramid_width, 2):
        print("{0:^{1}}".format("*" * asterisks, pyramid_width))
```

And neither worked. I am supposed to make `tests.py` to test the functions and I get errors for e.g

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akumaukpo\Documents\CISC 106\LAB05\lab05 _test.py", line 19, in <module>
    from lab05 import *
  File "C:\Users\akumaukpo\Documents\CISC 106\LAB05\lab05.py", line 22
    print i
        ^
```

Comment: Neither of those two examples you gave are recursive functions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every statement in a block must be indented by at least one space from the start of the block. The print statement in your code is not indented relative to the `for` block it is contained in, which is why you have the error.

Try this:

```
def asterix_triangle(depth):
        rows = [ (depth-i)*' ' + i*'*' + '*'   for i in range(depth) ]
        for i in rows:
            print i
```

Which yields:

```
>>> asterix_triangle(4)
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
```

EDIT:

I just realised your desired output is to have both halves of a triangle. If so, just mirror the string by adding the same thing to the right side of the string:

```
def asterix_triangle(depth):
        rows = [ (depth-i)*' ' + i*'*' + '*' + i*'*'  for i in range(depth) ]
        for j in rows:
            print j
```

The output:

```
>>> asterix_triangle(4)
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
```

Comment: Keep in mind that he said he wanted a recursive function. Not sure if he understands the difference between a normal and recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do a pyramid recursively you probably need to do something like this.

```
def asterix_triangle(i, t=0):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        print ' ' * ( i + 1 ) + '*' * ( t * 2 + 1)
        return asterix_triangle(i-1, t + 1)

asterix_triangle(5)
```

The idea is that you use two variables. One which is `i` that that subtract once every time the function is called and is used to end the cycle. The other variable is used to have an incremental increase. You then use `i` to print the number of spaces, and `t` the number of stars.

**The output would be:**

```
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(10):
print((' '*(10-i-1))+(('*')*((2*i)-1)))
```

[The output is as shown in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBBYp.jpg)

Comment: Your answer has several formatting or content problems. First it is not indented well. Second the output should be provided as text and not image (Image should be limited to specific case as they are not referenced). Third, you don't provide a code where you can choose the `depth` as the pyramid as asked in the question. You might need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) / to read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)