# Asterisk triangle in python

Tags: python, ascii-art

I have to write a recursive function asterisk_triangle which takes an integer and then returns an asterisk triangle consisting of that many lines.

For e.g this is a 4 line asterisk triangle.

```
*
**
***
****
```

I came up with this function:

```
def asterisk_triangle(n):
    """
    takes an integer n and then returns an
    asterisk triangle consisting of (n) many lines
    """
    x = 1
    while (x <= n):
        print("*" * x)
        x = x + 1
    return
```

And also I had to create an upside down asterisk triangle by manipulating the first function.

I came up with this function and result:

```
def upside_down_asterisk_triangle(n):
     """
     takes an integer n and then returns a backwards
     asterisk triangle consisting of (n) many lines
     """
     x = 0
     while (x < n):
          print("*" * (n-x))
     x = x + 1
     return


****
***
**
*
```

Now I have to manipulate these functions to create a backwards asterisk triangle.

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

And a backward upside down asterisk triangle.

```
****
 ***
  **
   *
```

What functions should I implement?

I have tried using the reverse string command [::-1] after the function and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you not just run the same loop just backwards?

Comment: Just gunna put this out there, but these functions are not currently recursive. Not sure if that was a core part of the requirement, but it might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I already answered the same question earlier. Keep in mind that none of the functions you mentioned are `recursive` functions. You can read more about recursion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

This is the example I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559435/need-to-recreate-pyramid-triangle-on-python/15559470#15559470).

**Python 3.X**

```
def asterix_triangle(i, t=0):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        print(' ' * ( i + 1 ) + '*' * ( t * 2 + 1 ))
        return asterix_triangle( i - 1, t + 1 )

asterix_triangle(5)
```

And here you have an upside down version of an recursive function.

```
def upside_down_asterix_triangle(i, t=0):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        print(' ' * ( t + 1 ) + '*' * ( i * 2 - 1 ))
        return upside_down_asterix_triangle( i - 1, t + 1 )

upside_down_asterix_triangle(5)
```

**Python 2.X**

```
def asterix_triangle(i, t=0):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        print ' ' * ( i + 1 ) + '*' * ( t * 2 + 1 )
        return asterix_triangle( i - 1, t + 1 )

asterix_triangle(5)
```

And here you have an upside down version of an recursive function.

```
def upside_down_asterix_triangle(i, t=0):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        print ' ' * ( t + 1 ) + '*' * ( i * 2 - 1 )
        return upside_down_asterix_triangle( i - 1, t + 1 )

upside_down_asterix_triangle(5)
```

**Edit:** *Screenshot showing the script running in my IDE.*

[image]

**Edit2:** *Added code that works under Python 3.x*

**Edit3:** *Added iterative function for Python 3.X*

```
def create_pyramid(rows):
    for i in range(rows):
        print((' ' * ( rows- i - 1 ) + '*' * ( 2 * i + 1)))

print((create_pyramid(5)))

def create_upside_down_pyramid(rows):
    for i in reversed(list(range(rows))):
        print((' ' * ( rows- i - 1 ) + '*' * ( 2 * i + 1)))

print((create_upside_down_pyramid(5)))
```

Comment: anytime i type the code you gave me in and run it, it gives a syntax error on the second quotation mark after "print"

Comment: @AkumaUkpo I updated the post with an alternative non-recursive function as well as a screenshot of the code layout on my computer.

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/66rd454eh/) [link](http://postimg.org/image/924gb08eh)    i took screenshots of the code and error message. what am i doing wrong? @Fuji

Comment: I added another version of the upside down pyramid. It is difficult to tell, maybe you are running Python 3.X? I would recommend that you remove any previous code as well to make sure it is not a type somewhere else.

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to mention, yes i am running python 3.3.0 @Fuji

Comment: @AkumaUkpo I updated with an example that runs under Python 3.X. https://ideone.com/w7uues

Comment: Thank you so much man. I have no errors when i run it now. However i'm still trying to derive an iterative function for backward_asterisk_triangle and a recursive function for backward_upside_down_asterisk_triangle @Fuji

Comment: I added one for you at the end.

Comment: error on second code https://ideone.com/iI13u3

Comment: supposed to be `reversed`, not `reverse`. Fixed.

Comment: i want to take a moment to thank you for all your help. However, the the triangles that your functions derive are not what the triangles in the assignment are supposed to look like. they are not supposed to be centered. i think this can be fixed by removing something from the code. Here take a look [link](http://postimg.org/image/bp4v98ytf/)

Comment: Simply change `2 * i + 1` to `i + 1` or `t * 2 + 1` to `t + 1`

Comment: okay i applied the changes to backward_asterisk_triangle and backward_upside_down_asterisk _triangle and they worked. (check last link i sent). however, asterisk_triangle isn't inverted (it leans to the left instead of the right) and upside_down_asterisk_triangle is the same (does not lean to right like supposed to) how do i alter the codes to display this?

Comment: @AkumaUkpo https://ideone.com/5cHU5q

Comment: these are the functions that work accurately so far - [link](http://postimg.org/image/l9uywz4nn/) the functions that are blank are the ones that wont work correctly (see the link i sent you before your last comment - the pdf assignment in img format) @Fuji

Comment: in the link you just sent me, i want the first two triangles to look mirrored (that is the main problem i'm having) @Fuji otherwise everything is good

Comment: Try this one. ;) https://ideone.com/FJQRRT

Comment: Omg, i cannot thank you enough man. You've offered the most help for hours. It finally worked. Thank you.