# Rearranging numbers from list in python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Lets say I have an list of numbers

a = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

and I want to print the output as

```
1
2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

How can I do it in python3.

***My attempt:***

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in a:
    print(a[i]," ")
    i=i+1
```

I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range` and also I don't know to print 1 element in 1'st row , 2nd and 3rd in second row and so on.

Comment: whats your approach ?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: That's doesn't look like an array.

Comment: (It is a list, not an array)

Comment: list is 1 dimensional array. isn't it?

Comment: Python has an actual [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) object, so it's better to not call a list (or a tuple) an array. And then there's Numpy arrays...

Comment: Beyond pedantism, arrays in most languages are homogeneous containers. Python lists are inhomogeneous; its elements can be arbitrary objects.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560730/asterisk-triangle-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this in Python 3 is to use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) on an [`iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) :

```
from itertools import islice

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
it = iter(a)
print('\n'.join([' '.join([str(u)for u in islice(it, i)])for i in range(1,5)]))
```

**output**

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```