# Using python, How can I make a pyramid using for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop

I've been having trouble in one of my classes with this problem, I can't quite figure it out. This is what we were asked to do.

"Write a program that only has one print command AND ONLY ONE PRINT COMMAND in a FOR loop to provide the following output. You may use another PRINT command outside the FOR/NEXT loop. The letter ‘Y’ can be used only one time in your program."

And it is supposed to look like this

Y
YY
YYY
YYYY
YYYYY
YYYYYY

I would love to know how to do this, it's been bugging me all week but it was only an extra credit question so my teacher never explained how to do it!! :(

Help is greatly appreciated!
-Alex

Comment: what is your closest attempt ... no one wants to spoil that ah-ha moment :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [need to recreate pyramid triangle on Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559435/need-to-recreate-pyramid-triangle-on-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something simple like this.

```
def create_pyramid(rows):
    for i in range(rows):
        print('Y' * ( i + 1))

create_pyramid(6)
```

Basically you set up a [for loop](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) with the number of rows you want. If you use [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)(number_of_rows)  you will get a loop that starts at 0 and goes to 1, 2 etc until it has looped 6 times. You then use this by [multiplying](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) the number of `Y` characters you want in on each line using `'Y' * i`, but keep in mind that the for loop starts counting from zero so you need to [add](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) `+ 1` to your `i` variable. Last you output the number of `Y` characters for each line to your screen using [print](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print).

**The output of this would be:**

```
Y
YY
YYY
YYYY
YYYYY
```

Comment: -1 for spoiling that ah-ha moment for him :( ... at least you explained it so +1 for that ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I deleted my answer for this reason :).

Comment: @JoranBeasley It is most likely based on this one http://postimg.org/image/bp4v98ytf/ and I know that there are at least a handful of duplicates here at stack without an actual explanation, so I thought I would actually give him an answer with an explanation for once so that he might actually learn something.

Comment: besides @JoranBeasley these types of answers does not deserve to get up-voted, but you know that this is the first place they will start looking, and if they are good enough at googling they'll find their answer.

Comment: Thanks! I really apppreciate this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in range(1,10):                    
    for j in range(0+i):        
    print 'y',        
 print '\n'
```

Comment: Tested in Python 3.5, this will not run

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(1,6+1):
    print ('Y'*x)
```

You can replace 6 with the number of rows.