# create the LEFT half of a triangle with * using only WHILE PYTHON

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have this code:

```
    numero = int(input("Escriba el número de filas de la pirámide: "))
if numero > 0:
    patron = "+"
    contador = 1
    while contador <= numero:
        print( patron * contador )
        contador = contador + 1
else:
    print("El número de filas de la pirámide debe ser mayor que 0")
```

[image: output]

I need this triangle to reverse like that:

[image: triangule reverse]

**I have solved it with FOR but in this case I want to do it with the conditional WHILE, which would be needed in the code?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recreate pyramid triangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559435/how-to-recreate-pyramid-triangle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pad, for this you can add as many spaces as needed:

```
numero = int(input("Escriba el número de filas de la pirámide: "))
if numero > 0:
    patron = "+"
    contador = 1
    while contador <= numero:
        print(' '*(numero-contador) + patron * contador)  # changed here
        contador = contador + 1
else:
    print("El número de filas de la pirámide debe ser mayor que 0")
```

If you can use string methods (`rjust`), it's even better:

```
print((patron * contador).rjust(numero))
```

output:

```
Escriba el número de filas de la pirámide: 6
     +
    ++
   +++
  ++++
 +++++
++++++
```